# Permission denied for file after using POST/GET in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, post, get, file-put-contents

I log every SQL errors into a file. This file has 646 as permissions, since I don't like 777. If a error occurs on the website, without handling with jQuery, the error message logs to the file. But when there's a error within a file that I calls through POST or GET in jQuery, I get permission denied. The file can be located so it's nothing about the error file is missing or anything.

Do I have to use some special commands through jQuery POST/GET, to get it to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

this has nothing to do with jQuery. it is only server side related.
I also use something like:

```
error_log("You messed up!", 3, "/var/ ... /my-errors.log");
```

check your server error logs and see the reason. I think the PHP script does not reach error writing sequence, it fails before that.